# Posting mutipart/form-data with RxJS ajax

Tags: ajax, django-rest-framework, rxjs, rxjs5

Is it possible to post multipart/form-data with RxJS Ajax observable? 
I tried to do so by setting `Content-Type` in ajax settings object like so.

```
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/ajax';

let data = {
  ad = 'ad_id',
  image = <HTML5 File object>
}

let settings = {
  url: '/some-url',
  body: data,
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=---------2e50046',
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

And used `ajax(settings)` to post the form

However, it does not seem to work when sent to backend server. I use `Django Rest Framework` in the backend.

I hope you can help me out on this.

Comment: What does "it does not seem to work" mean? Is there an error?

Comment: Also, why have you specified a boundary that ends with `--`? Two trailing hyphens is used to indicate the *last* boundary.

Comment: @cartant Sorry, I am actually using different boundary. It was just an example. Im gonna update it.

Comment: @cartant firstly, I'd like to know whether it is possible to post multipart/form-data with Rxjs ajax. The error shows on the backend side. I have two required felds: ad and image. Even thoush I post the right content. It responds back with 400 bad request: The ad and image fields are required.

Comment: You'd need to format the body yourself, as the [RxJS implementation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.2.0/src/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.ts#L269-L291) has no support for `multipart/form-data`. You might be off using something like [superagent](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#multipart-requests) and wrapping that in an observable if you need one.

Comment: @cartant, I see. Thanks for pointing this. Is superagent promise based? because I don't wanna use promises which are not cancellable. Are superagent requests cancellable?

Comment: It's event-based. There is an [`abort`](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#aborting-requests) method. Also, there is an RxJS plugin [here](https://github.com/yamalight/superagent-rx), but I've not used it. If nothing else, it should give you an idea of how superagent and RxJS could be combined.

Comment: @cartant, Thanks

Comment: No worries. Maybe post a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) when you get it working. Might be useful to someone else.